# Count mismatch for Unanswered questions

Tags: support, question-lists

This could be a minor bug, or maybe some cache issue, but I wanted to highlight that there is a count mismatch when we check the unanswered questions from the ["Questions" tab, "Unanswered" sub-tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=unanswered) and the ["Unanswered" tab](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest). If this is not a bug, then I would like to know what is the difference between these two tabs.

[image: "Questions" tab, "Unanswered" sub-tab]

[image: Unanswered tab]

Comment: We seriously need a Caching-Themesong...I propose the theme of [Malvin](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZGj6cUjl_qc)!

Comment: Note: 421 853 - are questions with **no upvoted answers** (at least on the picture). It's not the same as all unanswered questions.

Comment: @beryllium - Its the same. If you check the tooltip on the First image in SO, then you will find it says "question with no upvoted answers"

Comment: On SE sites, _unanswered questions_ is used to mean questions with no up-voted answers. This includes also questions without answers, since a question without answers doesn't have any up-voted answer.

Comment: hm, very interesting. now i can see that counts had changed and values are almost equal.

Answer (score 3):

It seems the pages are cached differently, as I see the same value for both the pages.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Its different at different times. I believe when there are new questions coming in at same time, the counts mismatch due to caching I believe. You can check after sometime again, that counts will again mismatch

Comment: That is because the pages are cached differently. What I mean is that the pages take their data from different caches, which are then rebuilt in different times (or set as invalid in different times).